# Magento dataflow import- 403 forbidden

Tags: php, magento

Hi guys I'm trying to import a csv file with the product catalog, but after some time it throws a 403 (forbidden) error...

I'm losing my mind with this...

Any sugestion in how can I solve this?

Answer (score 0):

Are you try deploy with this command?

```
magento setup:static-content:deploy
```

And can you try CHMOD and CHOWN again by this command

```
sudo chmod -R 777 /directory-of-magento-sites
sudo chown -R www-data:www-data /directory-of-magento-sites
```

After that please make sure you had clear all of cache

```
cd <your Magento install dir>/var
rm -rf cache/* composer_home/* log/* page_cache/* session/*
```

Comment: i dont have access to the terminal, but the magento directory as 0777 permission... any other suggestion?

Comment: What OS you using for?